Javascript: Await in async function calling async function?
async function foo() {
    return await db.collection("users").find({user_id:id}).toArray();
}


async function bar() {
    await foo()
}

Do I need both awaits here or can I remove one of them? If so which await should I remove?
What about in the scenario if I need to use the result of foo later in bar. Which "await" do I keep?

You can remove both of them in this example.

I think what @tkausl means is that the promises will "bubble through" and whatever code uses await to call bar() will deal with that. Now note that bar() doesn't return anything; that's OK, but you're losing what foo() returns.

@Pointy Good point, but what if I need to use the results of foo in bar?

then you'd need to await of course - i.e. const resultOfFoo = await foo()

Note: removing the async / await from bar will make it run differently, because the Promise chain will get broken and foo executes outside the chain.  But if you place return in front the chain is kept.

@Keith I'm not sure what you mean ? putting the return in front of await foo()?

@JaromandaX so do I need the await in foo() or not?

if that is the WHOLE function, it doesn't even need to be async

This question is similar to: Difference between `return await promise` and `return promise`. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@JobHunter69 Here's a [mre] of the code you provided using only a single await — in the TypeScript Playground: https://tsplay.dev/mq2MdW

I suspect you have over-simplified the issue in the post: if the db.collection method returns a promise then foo fails because the dot operator for member access (.) has higher priority than the await prefix operator, and promises don't have a find method. To make sense of the question please edit the post to say what the db.collection method actually returns.

@JobHunter69  No, just return foo(),  that return is not to return the value, but return the promise so the caller can continue the promise chain.  Without it, think of it as starting a new async context.

In practice, there's no problem in nesting async functions and await calls.
However, in the code you've provided these calls are useless as you're not doing any processing, but if you imagine that you want to process the data you can certainly optimize your code.
For example you can rewrite your first function :
// `async` means: this function will return a promise
async function foo() {
    // `await` means: wait for the promise to be resolved before executing further instructions
    // this means that `db.collection(...)...` also returns a promise
    return await db.collection("users").find({user_id:id}).toArray();
}

In this extract, you encapsulate a promise in another promise and wait for the resolution of the first before resolving the second.
This can be optimized as follows:
function foo() {
    // ... do what you want before
    // also return an unresolved promise
    return db.collection("users").find({user_id:id}).toArray();
}

async function bar() {
    // here we need `await` because we do something AFTER the promise resolution
    const result = await foo();
    console.log(result);
}

Remember that if await is the only and last instruction in your function, then await is certainly not necessary.
An example with then(...)
An example with then(...) might be more telling:
// Your code
function foo() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        db.collection("users").find({user_id:id}).toArray().then((result) => {
            resolve(result);
        })
    })
}

function bar() {
    foo().then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    })
}

// Optimized code
function foo() {
    return db.collection("users").find({user_id:id}).toArray()
}

function bar() {
    foo().then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
    })
}

I suggest you read this article to learn more about promises.

Your then version is not strictly the same..  your need return foo().then... otherwise it's not going to wait.  The return here is not to return the value, but to keep the promise chain in tact.

@Keith can you be more precise ? Because await foo() is strictly equivalent to foo().then(result => ...) and not return foo().then(result => ...).
